# AspNet Identity not using custom PasswordValidator code in IdentityConfig

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I've been trying to work this problem out for over a week and can't seem to work out why it isn't working. I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms.

I have updated the following on my IdentityConfig.vb file to reduce the password requirement so it doesn't need any uppercase or numeric value:

```
 manager.PasswordValidator = New PasswordValidator() With {
          .RequiredLength = 4,
          .RequireNonLetterOrDigit = False,
          .RequireDigit = False,
          .RequireLowercase = False,
          .RequireUppercase = False
        }
```

And this is the code I have to create a user

```
Protected Sub CreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userName As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
    Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
    Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = userName, .Email = userName}
    Dim result = manager.Create(user, TextBox2.Text)
    If result.Succeeded Then
        signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)
        Response.Redirect("/member")
    Else
    Literal1.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
    End If
End Sub
```

But for some reason no matter what I try it's using the default password requirement and giving me the following validation messages when trying to create an account.

> Passwords must be at least 6 characters. Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z'). Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').

I have moved the register page out of the /account section.

Does anybody know what I've done wrong?

Edit 1: Reference to ApplicationUserManager in my IdentityConfig file

```
Public Class ApplicationUserManager
    Inherits UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)
    Public Sub New(store As IUserStore(Of ApplicationUser))
        MyBase.New(store)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Create(options As IdentityFactoryOptions(Of ApplicationUserManager), context As IOwinContext) As ApplicationUserManager
        Dim manager = New ApplicationUserManager(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(context.[Get](Of ApplicationDbContext)()))
        ' Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser)(manager) With {
          .AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False,
          .RequireUniqueEmail = True
        }

        ' Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = New PasswordValidator() With {
          .RequiredLength = 4,
          .RequireNonLetterOrDigit = False,
          .RequireDigit = False,
          .RequireLowercase = False,
          .RequireUppercase = False
        }
        ' Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user. '
        ' You can write your own provider and plug in here. '
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", New PhoneNumberTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser)() With {
          .MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        })
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", New EmailTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser)() With {
          .Subject = "Security Code",
          .BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        })

        ' Configure user lockout defaults '
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = True
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5

        manager.EmailService = New EmailService()
        manager.SmsService = New SmsService()
        Dim dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider
        If dataProtectionProvider IsNot Nothing Then
            manager.UserTokenProvider = New DataProtectorTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser)(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
        End If
        Return manager
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Can you show your "ApplicationUserManager" class ? just to see if you actually set the PasswordValidator property to your new updated "PasswordValidator" object.